# Variable importance not defined in mlr3 rpart learner

Tags: r, decision-tree, mlr3

I trained and tested a decision tree classifier with mlr3 package in R:

`pred_probability = learner_DT$train(task_train)$predict(task_test)`

How can I get the variable importance from this model? I tried `learner_DT$importance()` but the outcome was `named numeric(0)`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks right (you don't need to call `$predict()` to get the importance, but it doesn't hurt). The documentation of rpart.object states:

> variable.importance: a named numeric vector giving the importance of each
> variable.  (Only present if there are any splits.)  When printed
> by 'summary.rpart' these are rescaled to add to 100.

So possibly you've fitted a tree without splits (you should see this in the printed output of `learner_DT$model`).